# Filter tcpdump capture to gather info on DNS/URL/URI

Tags: tcpdump

I'm looking to extract the DNS/URL/URI information from packets and produce a CSV output which I can then feed into flowtag.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend WireShark for this purpose, but 
Hope this may be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777042/can-i-use-tcpdump-to-get-http-requests-response-header-and-response-body